# When I click on "24 comments" under a post, it no longer expands the comment section

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

It's been a week that my Facebook news feed acts weirdly. It stopped expanding the comment section under posts.

Before, I would click on, for example, "24 comments" under a post and the comments section would expand to let me see the comments. I must imagine that this is the normal behaviour.

However, it recently started to act differently. Now, when I click on, for example "24 comments" under a post, it opens a new page with the profile of the page that posted, with the post highlighted in blue and the comments section opened. I can't imagine that this is the intended behaviour.

I tested this on different computers -- Mac, PC -- and on different browsers, and the problem is the same so it looks like it is specific to my FB account.

It's not that it's that disturbing, it's just that I'm curious as to why I experience this and not the people around me.

Comment: Clear the cache of your browser or login in any other browser. Check if you see the same behavior. Expand the post by clicking on the post and see if you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue multiple times over the past few years, in my experience, the issue just goes away after a week or two, it's quite annoying but so far its all been resolved without me emailing Facebook support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and it is so annoying. I want to see the comments but cannot. This has been going on for about two weeks so I hope it does clear up soon. I've tried logging off and logging on and nothing changes.